# Where must I include the require("twitter") code in my cordova application?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova, twitter

I am trying to create a cross platform application using cordova, I am using the https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter library for javascript. In my file file.js which I reference in my index.html, I have included:

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

    var client = new Twitter({
        consumer_key: '***',
        consumer_secret: '***',
        access_token_key: '***',
        access_token_secret: '***'
    });

    client.post('statuses/update', { status: 'Testing 123' }, function (error, tweet, response) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(tweet);  // Tweet body. 
        console.log(response);  // Raw response object. 
    });
```

However, the java script console gives some errors from which:**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**.
I searched about it and learned that this is used in the server side. Therefore I was wondering how to execute this code. Where am I supposed to include it? How can it be called?

Answer (score -1):

Nowhere. The library you are using is called "Twitter for Node.js"

Cordova is not Node.js. It is an environment for running in the web view of a smartphone application.

You need to find a library designed to run in a browser (or specifically for Cordova) not one for Node.js.

Comment: I need to find a twitter library for javascript, https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient.git is one of them, however it still uses the required part. What are your suggestions? I need to use the twitter api which also needs Oauth. How can I approch this problem?

Comment: You need to find a twitter library which is compatible with the particular JavaScript environment you are using. That environment is not Node.js. https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient also expects to run in Node.js. The documentation says "packaged as a node module" and "from NodeJS"